# In which direction to make the association in domain model

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture, uml, domain-driven-design

Is there some rule of thumb, in which direction to make the association when designing domain model?

For example, we have products in the stock. Stock status of a product is a rather complex data structure, containing enumerations of multiple variations of the product either being in the stock, being out of stock or being bookable. Thus we make a seperate object of the stock status associated with the product. *Now the question is, if product object should have a reference to it's stock status, or stock status have a reference to a particular product*.

First solution feels like, it's not the real concern of product knowing it's stock state. Product is just a product, and maybe we should manipulate them in different context, where stocking is not a concern. In  the other hand, stock status being a root feels awkward, as when thinking about stock, first we *think* about a product being in the stock.

How to decide, which entity acts as a root for the association?

Answer (score 1):

Navigability is something you should simply neglect as it is something purely artificial. If two things are related, they know about each other. Actio et reactio. Gravity. Love. Try hard to find something that works only in one direction. Blackmail. Spy mirrors.

Introducing navigability indeed has only meaning in implementation phase. You try to decouple things in order to reduce dependencies, now for good. And what you actually do here is to attach role names towards the navigation. Which in turn makes the arrows superfluous.

TL;DR; Just don't use arrows in UML modeling. Leave them for the Powerpoint League.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that both concepts are tightly coupled, meaning, they belong to the same bounded context. This means both models become dependent on each other - which may be something you don't want because it causes complexity you may not want. After all, you mentioned it yourself: "it's not the real concern of product knowing it's stock state". So why add a relation to it?

You could consider them as two separate bounded contexts - no direct relation between them, except for the product ID which links the two concepts.

Answer (score 0):

> First solution feels like, it's not the real concern of product knowing it's stock state. Product is just a product, and maybe we should manipulate them in different context, where stocking is not a concern. In the other hand, stock status being a root feels awkward, as when thinking about stock, first we think about a product being in the stock.

When we think about shopping carts, we think about products in the shopping cart.  Yet most of the time, the useful way to model cart items is with a reference back to the product.

My guess would be that you need to be thinking more about `Stock`, and in particular about its life cycle; how tightly coupled are the lifetimes of the two different ideas?  If you have a situation where a single `Product` has a relation to two different `Stocks` (one in the past, one in the present; one at this location, another at that location), then storing that relationship in the product isn't right.